# SSL сертификат на modx evolution

Tags: .htaccess, modx, ssl

SSL приобретён и настроен на хостинге.
«Тип сервера» в Инструменты --> Конфигурация --> Сайт выбран «https».

При установке редиректа в .htaccess с http на https появляется бесконечный редирект.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Кто встречался с такой проблемой и какой код в .htaccess оказался рабочий?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что на это влияет настройка самого MODX? Если создать простой файл test.html и открыть его через https - он открывается? Могу предположить, что нет. Проверьте и напишите результат. Потому что проблема множественного редиректа явно не в .htaccess - у вас бы тогда и не происходило редиректа. А происходит следующее - .htaccess редиректит на https, хостинг же в свою очередь либо считает что сертификат настроен некорректно и обратно редиректит на http или просто стоит настройка "перенаправлять с https на http" в итоге .htaccess опять перенаправляет на https и так по кругу.

Comment: И еще, полезно было бы узнать что за хостинг. Так как у них тоже у каждого свои заморочки и такая ситуация может быть на каждом хостинге из-за разных причин.

Comment: sweb.ru Как вы и говорили попробовал создать файл, открывается через http. Посоветовали плагин SSL 1.0.0-ga. Итог всё тот же бесконечный редирект.

Comment: Тут проще написать в саппорт свеба. Т.к. если включен ssl и сертификат настроен корректно - не должно с https на http перекидывать. А вот если все-таки сайт не ssl или где-то слетела настройка, или сертификат не подходит/просрочен - то свеб автоматом на http перекидывает